# APEX 5 error - numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I work on APEX 5 application and have IR displaying numeric values for 31 days of month (there are 31 columns). I need every column to be link to another modal page. I set every column as Link but when page loads, get error

> **numeric or value error: character string buffer too small**.

If I leave only 25 columns to be Link and rest of them to be Plain Text, it works fine. But if I change 26. column to be link, get an error.
What is the problem?

Comment: Are all your day columns hyperlinks? If so, can you remove links and check if you are able to add more columns to your report without any errors.

Comment: Yes, all days are hyperlinks. I need to be redirected to page with details for that day. If I remove links I am able to add more columns, it works fine.