# Data grid - large number of columns cause numeric or value error

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I'm trying to use Interactive Grid for displaying a table with a large number of columns (150). The problem is that at about 80 columns (number varies with column names and types) the page starts showing the following message:

> Error during rendering of region "Data Grid Test".
>
> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too
>   small
>
> Technical Info (only visible for developers)
>
> 1. is_internal_error: true
> 2. apex_error_code: APEX.REGION.UNHANDLED_ERROR
> 3. ora_sqlcode: -6502 ora_sqlerrm: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
> 4. component.type:
>      APEX_APPLICATION_PAGES
> 5. component.id: 135591000000002
> 6. component.name: Data Grid Test
> 7. error_backtrace: ORA-06512: at
>      "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_DISP_PAGE_PLUGS", line 997

I presume that there is a finite yet unknown amount of fields/elements you can put in a row as I have encountered a similar error before: it was in APEX 5.0 with tabular forms that had too many display and LOV columns (especially with select lists mith large number of entries), none of which I use right now (also found the unanswered related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837560/apex-5-error-numeric-or-value-error-character-string-buffer-too-small)). There doesn't seem to be a hard limit to a number of columns in the interactive data grid. Making the grid editable makes the number of columns before the error appears even smaller. So basically the question comes down to:

**Is there a way to display and edit a table with large number of columns (150) using Interactive grid without running into the mentioned error?**

Note that single row edit is not a solution for me tabular edit is a part of the requirements. Splitting the row editing into multiple forms/pages also isn't acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

this error is causing havoc we just applied patch to upgrade to Apex 5.1.3x and the error is still there. so i suggest you split your table into 2 via interactive grids then conditionally display one or the other - whichever is display displayed let users edit/add...regards Enock.

Comment: As I said, splitting the row in multiple forms/pages/grids in this case isn't really viable (as client won't accept it) but it can be used as a last resort.